# Maven - What's the meaning for property "autoDetectPrefix"?

Tags: maven

I have a case that for a project with managed by maven and its POM file contains true, but only works for Mac, and I have to comment this on Ubuntu, so I try to search in maven world what does this property mean, unluckily there is very few reference here. Anyone has the idea here? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the error message that you are encountering on Ubuntu

Comment: Sorry it's not very easy to attach the error message as it contains the company code info here.